# How do I split up multiple scene classes in manim-slides?

Tags: manim

I want to have some form of separation between classes, where I can define methods have some encapsulation. Can I do this with `manim-slides`? The closest workaround I've found is this, but it completely bypasses the fact that `Scene1` is a `Slide` class:

```py
from manim_slides import Slide

class Scene1(Slide):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene

    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle(radius=3, color=BLUE)
        dot = Dot()
        self.scene.play(GrowFromCenter(circle))

class Test(Slide):
    def construct(self):
        scene1 = Scene1(self)
        scene1.construct()
        self.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue a while back. A helpful person (Abulafia#3734) on the Manim Discord channel provided me with this solution.

I'm not sure why you would want to override `__init__` in your code. If you want to have attributes that can be accessed in `construct` then you can put your attribute declarations in another method (for example `setup`) and call it along with `construct` in the main class.

```py
from manim import *
from manim_slides import Slide


class Scene1(Slide):
    def setup(self):
        self.circle = Circle(radius=3, color=BLUE)

    def construct(self):
        self.play(GrowFromCenter(circle))


class Test(Slide):
  def construct(self):
      all_scenes = [Scene1]  # List of all scenes
      for cls in all_scenes:
          cls.setup(self)
          cls.construct(self)
```

A potential downside to this solution is that if you can't split subscenes from `Scene1.construct` like this:

```py
class Scene1(Slide):
    def setup(self):
        self.circle = Circle(radius=3, color=BLUE)

    def _create_circle(self):
        self.play(GrowFromCenter(circle))

    def _create_dot(self):
        self.play(Create(Dot())

    def construct(self):
        self._create_circle()
        self._create_dot()
```

Calling `Scene1.construct` from `Test` will result in `attribute '_create_circle' not found` or something like that. If anyone has another solution then I'm happy to hear it as well.